# How do I migrate dumps database (users.sql) inside php laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I already have dump database(users.sql) inside the MySQL workbench. How do I migrate it inside php laravel? I already make:migrations created_users_table. Means I already connect the database with the php laravel projects. But, I noticed, the value of Users.sql (data) doesn't insert to the table in php. It means I didn't dump the database inside the php laravel project, right?

Comment: by running `mysql -uroot -ppasword database_name < users.sql` in your vm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist your Users data in your Laravel project you can use seeder ([The documentation is here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding)).

With seeder, you can create a class with some data and, after run this command

```
php artisan db:seed --class=NameOfYourSeederClass
```

you can insert your data in your MySql table every time you install your project.

You have to manually create you seeder with your Sql data but if you export your data in CSV on JSON format you can dynamically create your seeder with this script: [Data to Laravel seeders](https://github.com/steve-polite/data-to-laravel-seeder)